# Weyl sequence for oscillator harmonic

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Consider the operator $T=-\Delta_{\Bbb{R}^2}-(x^2+y^2)$.

How can I construct a sequence $ (u_n)\in D(T)=\{u\in L^2(R^2); Tu\in L^2(R^2)\}$ such that  $\|u_n\|=\sqrt{\int_{R^2}|u(x,y)|^2}=1,$ $u_n\to 0$ weakly, and $\lim_n \|Tu_n\|=0.$

Note that such sequence exists because 0 belongs in the spectrum of $T$ noted $\sigma(T)$ and by the weyl's criterion.

Comment: Interesting. What norm is $\|\cdot\|$? And what is $D(T)$ exactly? Finally, how do you know that such a sequence exists?

Comment: Thanks for your remark, see above.